# openWYSIWYG  disabled textarea

Tags: textarea, openwysiwyg

Is there anyone here uses openWYSIWYG 1.4.7?

I wanted to display only my textarea by calling

```
WYSIWYG.display('textarea1');
```

And I want the text on my textarea not to be selectable that's why I tried this

```
<textarea1 id=textarea1 name='test1' disabled  ></textarea>
```

but it doesn't work.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt if you can prevent selecting the text in text area directly. 
You can try placing an element like iframe on top of with with higher Z-index.. so when the user selects what they see as a test area, he will actually be interacting with transparent iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Please keep in mind that any such protection(including the one above) should be not used as a security option. User can always find a way to go select the text or even edit it before submitting it.. they can use web developer plugins like Firebug to do the trick.

Even HTTPS cant prevent this, when the user is itself doing the trick in his browser. 
You do your validation in server side, if applicable.

Comment: thanks for the reminder, I thought the user won't able to select the text by adding element at top of it. I did select all and I've seen that the text selected. Any suggestion to perfectly prevent selecting text?

Comment: There is a saying be web security guys.. "If you want to keep something secret, keep it in your server. Anything sent to client side, is a permission to copy" :) no exception! You can even try sending your data as a image, where user literally cant copy by selecting.. but, he can type by seeing the image or there are many online tools which converts image to text. You can try sing Firebug and it will tell you how open your web page's data is for an user to copy or manipulate it.